# How to compute the address at which the page table entry?

Tags: virtualization

Suppose a system has:

20-bit virtual addresses,
1024 byte pages,
24-bit physical addresses,
4 byte page table enties,
a page table base pointer set to physical (byte) address 0x1000,
a single-level page table structure.

Based on the above information, what is the address at which the page table entry for the virtual address 0x1000 is stored? (Note that page table entries are larger than one byte.) Write your answer as a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 0):

1024 (2^10) byte pages -> page offset = 10

virtual address 0x1000 -> 100 0000000000

VPN: 100 -> 0x4

PTE address =  0x1000(page table base pointer) + 0x4(VPN)* 4(size of PTE) = 0x1010

So the correct answer is 0x1010.